# Pixel accurate hit detection on images in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a basic isometric map with some sprites loaded on the map in a html canvas.

I am wondering though, is it possible to click the canvas, to a pixel accurate level and have JS work out what you clicked in the canvas?

If so is there also a way to do it without a library?

Comment: Intereresting question. However, maybe you should have posted it on gamedev.stackexchange.com instead :)

Comment: I almost never get responses there :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Canvas API has the [isPointInPath(x, y)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-ispointinpath) method, which allows you to determine if a point (x, y) is inside the current path (or on it).

Now if you already have many shapes in your canvas and want to know which one was clicked, and do not want to use a library, you will have to maintain a list or map of objects representing those shapes and have an `onclick` event handler that iterates through it and performs some calculations.

Such a list could look like

```
var shapeList = [
    {shape: "rect",   x0: 100, y0: 100, x1: 200, y1: 150},
    {shape: "circle", x0: 400, y0: 400, r: 50},
    ...
];
```

Fortunately, there are libraries out there that can do this job for you. You can check for instance [crafty.js](http://craftyjs.com) or [lime.js](http://www.limejs.com). These are useful libraries for Canvas game development.

For exemple, using Crafty's [containsPoint(x, y)](http://craftyjs.com/api/Crafty-Polygon.html#-containsPoint%20crafty.js) method:

```
var circle = new Crafty.circle(0, 0, 10);
console.log(circle.containsPoint(0, 0));   // true
console.log(circle.containsPoint(50, 50)); // false
```

Comment: Can you explain that second snippet of code you posted.. in terms of what is is doing?

Comment: if i had 20 + images to check i would have to have do a check on all of them to get true or false :S ?

Comment: @Dave The second snippet simply creates a circle whose center is located at (0, 0) and whose radius is 10px. Then it checks if the circle contains the point (0, 0) (it is true), and the point (50, 50), (it is false).

Comment: @Dave If you have many fixed shapes, you could consider using a map where each key represents a pixel of your canvas, and each value the shape containing that pixel. Such a map could be pretty big, so if many pixels are not associated with any shape at all it would be advisabe not to include them in the map. Then a single lookup would tell you which shape a given pixel belongs to, if any.